# ComplexType with Association

Tags: entity-framework

The documentation on MSDN is clear on this topic:
"ComplexTypes cannot contain Associations"

When reading about complex types, the most used example is the Address ComplexType:

```
class Person
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to define the Country as an association:

```
class Address
{
    //other properties ....
    public Country Country { get; set; } //vs: string CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I would like to add an association to a Country in the Address ComplexType. Unfortunately this is not possible. This makes the complete example pointless because I would have to define the Country association on the Person type itself which would make the whole Address-CT useless.

We are currently setting up a Project using NHibernate because EF lacks some of the features we need for our project but which will most likely be supported in EF 6. Considering the fast evolving of EF and the recently announced open-source model, we want to keep a possible migration from NH to EF open for the future. 
In NHibernate ComplexTypes ("Components") do support Associations so a migration to EF would not be easily possible if we would use them now with NH.

I would like to know if this is just a current limitation?

- Are there plans to support such a feature in the future?
- Is there an explict reason for not supporting this feature or is it just "not implemented  atm"?

Comment: That is a design question you should ask directly to [ADO.NET team](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions).

Comment: Ok, I will post it there. Thx for the link.

Comment: Keep in mind that ComplexTypes in EF are reusable so more than one entity can have a property of the same ComplexType. Therefore it is not really feasible to have an Association betwen a property of a Complex Type and another property since such an Association would probably not work if the Complex Type is used in multiple entities. The way it could work however (if implemented) would be to define an Association which would point to a property on the complex type as to be the "end" (in terms of ends of a relationship/RelatedEnd property).

Comment: Btw. the feature has already been requested here: You can vote up this feature on user voice: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2132793-allow-complex-types-to-reference-entities. Feel free to vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

There are possible plans as noted in the comments.

On the second question, I'd say "just at this moment".

I think it is unreasonable not to have this feature if the developer has an explicit reason for it. Yes, it should be used wisely, but shouldn't any API?

Not every entity is associated with another directly, so limiting this makes no sense. If I have an `Address` that must reference an entity, why is this any different than a single property refencing an entity?

A complex type in this context is no different from a simple type. Perhaps a complex type can be identified as "reusable" in certain contexts. But it seems like under DDD "rules" there is no real reason a complex type can't reference an entity.